# Network response and getJSON data differ, data is incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, json

So I'm getting json response from my controller, which looks simply like:

```
return Plan::find($request->id)->toJson();
```

and when I'm looking in the 'Network' tab in browser developer tools, the response is correct. But at the same time, I want these data to be logged in console, so in javascript I have:

```
$.getJSON('{{action("Controller@getJSON")}}',{id}).success(function(data) {
console.log(data);});
```

And here some data are incorrect, being randomly changed to other data from this response. In particular, datetimes are being changed, for example, `start` and `end` become equal, both with value of one of them. What is this and how could it be fixed?

UPD: well, it looks like the problem is with vue.js that I'm using to control data. for now, the vue method that gets data looks as follows:

```
updatePlan: function(id) {
    var json;
    $.getJSON('{{action("Controller@getJSON")}}',{id}).success(function(data) {
    {media_plan: id}).success(function(data) {
        json=data;
        animatedOpenModal('edit-button','editPlanModal');                       
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(json);
        //vm.setPlan(json);
    },100);
},
```

and the commented method is

```
setPlan: function(json) {
    vm.$set('current_edit_plan', json);
    console.log(vm.current_edit_plan);                  
},
```

and for now console.log shows correct data, but if I remove // - everything will fall apart

Comment: are you setting and getting correct headers in response, and is it JSON encoded? can you check by emulating the same request?

Comment: I found out that it's vue.js what causes trouble. when I just get data, everything is okay, but when I try to make vm.$set in array, everything goes to hell

Comment: Yawning Milk, then you need to edit your question correspondingly. It's hard to troubleshoot and not to have the full picture. Please, extend your question and provide all the related input. Thanks.

Comment: @Farside I added vue code snippets, hope it helps